# FPTAS for knapsack with private valuations

Tags: algorithms, approximation, knapsack-problems

The Knapsack problem has a [well-known FPTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Fully_polynomial_time_approximation_scheme) based on rounding and then using the pseudopolynomial dynamic programming algorithm. When the valuations $v_i$ are private, we also need the assignment rule to be monotonic (i.e., if a player gets included in the knapsack, then if he increases his bid/valuation, he should still be in the knapsack.) However, the well-known FPTAS does not seem to satisfy this because of rounding. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The [standard Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) doesn't have any notion of "players" or of "increasing a bid/valuation".  Can you please give a more precise specification of your problem, and a precise definition of what you mean by an "assignment rule" and what it means for an "assignment rule" to be "monotonic"?